# Как определить вхождение подстрок в строку на PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пусть переменная содержит строку:

```
$str = 'page=2&area=&city=&price=&rating=asc';
```

Если строка включает подстроки `page=2&` или `page=n&`, тогда удалить переменную `$str`.

Comment: Используйте функцию preg_replace

Comment: $str = preg_replace('/page=[0-9]+&?/','',$str);

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$str = 'page=2&area=&city=&price=&rating=asc';

//Выполняет проверку на соответствие регулярному выражению
if (preg_match("/(page=2&|page=n&)/i", $str)) {
    unset($str);  //удаляет переменную
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'page=2&area=&city=&price=&rating=asc';
$result = [];
parse_str($str, $result);

print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [page] => 2
    [area] => 
    [city] => 
    [price] => 
    [rating] => asc
)
```

Дальше делайте выводы